# How to open a new terminal tab in Mac OS X with working directory same as the current terminal tab

Tags: macos, terminal, working-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X Terminal.app: how to start a new tab in the same directory as the current tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/61149/os-x-terminal-app-how-to-start-a-new-tab-in-the-same-directory-as-the-current-ta)

This is the default behavior in Ubuntu: when you open an new tab in a terminal, the working directory of the new tab is the same as the one from which you opened the new tab. Is there a way to do that in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on SuperUser:
[OS X Terminal.app: how to start a new tab in the same directory as the current tab](https://superuser.com/questions/61149/os-x-terminal-app-how-to-start-a-new-tab-in-the-same-directory-as-the-current-ta)

Comment: OK, thanks, but it seems really complicated. There must be an easier and cleaner way to do it, isn't there?

Comment: @seb I don't know, but I do know (no offense intended) that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.